# Existene (and if true ,classifiation) of monotonic coninuous-everywhere differentiable-nowhere functions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, asymptotics, monotone-functions

Do there exist non-differentiable continuous functions that are monotonic, i.e. which throughout its domain de- or in- creases exlusively?

And what are asymptotic behaviors of functions satisfying these conditions? Do there exist constructible non-differentiable continuous monotonic functions whose magnitudal growth/decay rates respectively are asymptotically slower than logarithmic, faster than exponential, and everywhere (algebraically discernible) inbetween?

Comment: Monotonic functions are differentiable almost everywhere, in particular on  a dense see of points.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy.  Oh. interesting. Mind elaborating, i.e. on "almost everywhere" and "dense see{sp?} of points"?   I apologize if this has obvious answer or if it has been answered already here (and if any the tags are wrong / not optimal).  If you wouldn't mind, please consider directing to appropriate post (and to get this closed) or typing an Answer.

Comment: The proof requires measure theory. There is no Calculus proof of this fact.

Comment: [Lebesgue's Theorem on the Differentiability of Monotone Functions](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-theorem-for-the-differentiability-of-monotone-fun). [Elementary Proof Of The Lebesgue’s Differentiation Theorem](http://web.boun.edu.tr/fatih.ecevit/Math480SamplePresentation.pdf).